# Bash: expect + scp : Problem on multiple files

Tags: bash, file-upload, expect, scp

```
function expect_password {
    expect -c "\
    set timeout 90
    set env(TERM)
    spawn $1
    expect \"password:\"
    send \"$password\r\"
    expect eof
  "
}

expect_password "scp /home/kit.ho/folder/file1 root@$IP:/usr/bin"
```

The above `expect_password` works perfect!

However, I want to transfer multiple files in that directory, so I tried:

```
expect_password "scp /home/kit.ho/folder/* root@$IP:/usr/bin"
```

But an error comes up:

```
/home/kit.ho/folder/*: No such file or directory
Killed by signal 1.
```

It seems that `expect` doesn't recognize `*`. How can I transfer files in that way?
There is a possible answer using `rsync` but I can't use that.

Comment: More along the lines of the shell trying to expand the wildcard. Try escaping the `*`, so it's `\*` instead (or even `\\*`, depending on how many levels of parsing are occuring).

Comment: I have try `\*` , `\\*`, `\\\*`  all doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manpage of expect says "If  program  cannot  be  spawned successfully because exec(2) fails", so I assume that expect uses exec internally. exec doesn't call any shell to do wildcard expansion and such magic, which means that your ssh sees the asterisk and can't handle it. Have you tried to call your shell explicitely like

```
expect_password "sh -c \"scp /home/kit.ho/folder/* root@$IP:/usr/bin\""
```

(maybe you need to omit the single quotes)?

edit:
use \" instead of '

Comment: Great! Your answer has a bit incorrect, let me help u to edit `\"` instead of `'`. Btw, I got what you meaning, I think expect doesn't recognize my * as a wildcard, use sh -c is a good choice!

Comment: The \" sounds a bit strange to me, since $IP should be expanded by /your/ shell even before the expect gets called. However, feel free to edit, I don't see any bad in that.

Answer (score 1):

Expect is an extension of Tcl, and Tcl does not speak shell-filename-globbing natively. Rather than shoe-horning a Tcl solution withing your framework, try

```
set -- /home/kit.ho/folder/* 
expect_password "scp $* root@$IP:/usr/bin"
```

Files with spaces won't work properly with this solution.

Comment: What does `set -- /home/kit.ho/folder/*` this actually mean? I am quite new on linux

Comment: That sets the positional parameters ($1, $2, $3 etc). When I use $* in the argument to expect_password, it expands to all the names of the files/subdirs in that folder

Answer (score 0):

Can't you leave away the password stuff completely and work with SSH public keys?

Comment: i know there is a way but I can't do that due to security issues along the server side.